# Как отключить тёмную тему браузера у себя на сайте? Необходимо найти решение, как к сайту запретить применять темную тему

Tags: css

Необходимо найти решение, как к сайту запретить применять темную тему

Comment: Вы про `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark)`?. Причем здесь теги `google`, `wordpress`, `php`?

Comment: полезно, но я немного не об этом. Я не могу принудительно переключить тему браузера пользователя на светлую или сообщить как-то браузеру, что мой сайт не поддерживает тёмную тему?

Comment: Если у Вас нет `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) { стили-для-dark-mode }` то темная тема не должна применяться. Возможно, у Вас браузер, который сам это пытается сделать (CSS переопределять)? Нужно искать решения для конкретного браузера. Я Вам написал, когда применяются стили для темной темы через CSS автора сайта, как, например, в Safari для macOS.

Comment: какое решение нашли? Можно как-то запретить переводить сайт в темную тему? Столкнулся с проблемой отображения сайта на некоторых устройствах андроид

Comment: Не нашёл решения(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если браузер определяет свои стили поверх ваших, то попытайтесь сделать ваши более специфичными. Нет ничего более специфичного, чем инлайн-стиль с `!important`, если что.

Если браузер делает стили темными на уровне движка (например, определяет светлые цвета для фонов как черный, а цвета для текстов как белый, то у меня для вас плохие новости.

А еще пользователь может поставить какой-нибудь плагин (или даже написать его сам), который скриптом пройдется по элементам вашего сайта и повыкидывает ваши инлайн- и не-инлайн-стили оттуда. Тоже облом.

Поэтому все, что вам остается - сверстать сайт в светлой теме как вы хотите, сделать скриншоты, и вставить их в качестве содержимого вашего сайта. Это точно поможет... если пользователь, конечно, не наложит инвертирующий фильтр =))))

Война снаряда и брони предстоит тебе, юный падаван. И нет в ней конца и полной победы.